# How to implement the menu that appears when sliding an element to the side on nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am going over the docs but I can't find what I'm looking for. The type of animation I want is for example what you have when looking at your email on iOS where you can slide the individual mail to a side and then you get the option to archive, delete, etc.

Is there a way to make something like this for Nativescript?

I figured it'd be a variation of the listview but I'm not 100% positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RadListView (plugin [nativescript-ui-listview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-ui-listview)) have a swipe actions functionality that is basically what you are describing. More information [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/swipe-actions)